# How to set the Content of Label based on Button Click 

Tags: c#, wpf, button, mvvm, label

I have a method in my viewmodel class which is invoked by a button click and does some operations. Now I have a label and button in my xaml file:

```
<Label Content="" Height="20" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,50,0,0" Name="label1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="119" />
<Button Content="Sync" Height="23" Command="{Binding Path=SyncCommand}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,15,0,0" Name="button1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100" />
```

My View Model:

```
    // This method is called when Sync Button is Clicked
    public void SyncCommandExecuted()
    {            
        string strBadResp = string.Empty;  
        Byte[] sendBuf = new Byte[256];
        Byte[] readBuf = new Byte[256];          
        sendBuf[0] = 0x80;
        mComm.setAddress(0x3e);
        mComm.WriteBytes(4, sendBuf);

        if (mComm.ReadBytes(4, ref readBuf) != 0)
        {                
            for (int cnt = 0; cnt < 4; cnt++ )
            {
                if (readBuf[cnt] != null)
                {
                    sendBuf[cnt] = readBuf[cnt];                        
                }
                else
                {                        
                    strBadResp = "Bad response";

                    // Here I want to display the content in strBadResp i.e. BAD RESPONSE on a label
                    sendBuf = null;                        
                }
            }

            if (sendBuf != null)
            {
                strBadResp = BitConverter.ToString(sendBuf);

                // Here I want to display the content in strBadResp on a label
            }                
        }
    }
```

My ReadBytes method stores the following:

```
byteArray[0] = 0x01;
byteArray[1] = 0x02;
byteArray[2] = 0x03;
byteArray[3] = 0x04;
```

So basically at both the places the result(**strBadResp**) shud be in a label. I hope I have made it clear. I am new into this WPF world. Please help!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bind the content property on your label to a property on the view model. Update the response property when you want to update the label.

**View**

```
<Label Content="{Binding Response}" Height="20" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,50,0,0" Name="label1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="119" />
```

**ViewModel**

```
public class YourViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged {

    string response;

    public string Response {

        get  { return this.response; }

        set {
            if (this.response == value)
                return;

            this.response = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Response");
        }
    }

    public event NotityPropertyChangedEventHandler  = delegate {}

    void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName) {
        PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName);   
    }
  }
```

Comment: After adding the code above, I just added Response = strBadResp; and I got it :) Thanks Per.

Answer (score 1):

You have to create object of Lable in code behind as below.

```
var lableMSG = new Lable();

lableMSG.Content = "Message string";
```

hope this will help you!!

Comment: I am following MVVM pattern. Ur answer is not what i am expecting :(